# SVM - confusion between vectors and points

Tags: machine-learning, theory, svm

Why in the theory of support vector machines, the points from the training set which lie on the margin of the maximum-margin hyperplane are called the support vectors? They are points, aren't they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this situation, points and vectors are really [the same thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space).

Given some fixed origin, each point in space can be described by a vector, and conversely, every vector defines a point in space.

EDIT (based on comment):

The hyperplane is chosen so that it best separates the two classes. It only depends on the vectors nearest the hyperplane - these are called the "support" vectors. The picture on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) clasifies this.

Comment: I think I now get it, the separating hyperplane is defined by a vector which is really a linear combination of the points from the training set, which in turn can be treated as vectors. That's why they call them support vectors.

Comment: Actually the support vectors (points) are those `x_i`'s from the dataset, that have the corresponding `alpha_i`'s set to non-zero values in the `Lagrange multipliers` problem statement. See the wikipedia article posted by @daoudc.

Comment: I think what really answers my question is what @daoudc said in his first response, that is that a point can be defined by a vector at a fixed origin.